# Updated--Issue with sensors connecting to Arduino Uno via Atlas Scientific hardware serial port expander 8:1

Tags: gps, arduino-uno

Hardware connection and also programming issue with sensors (GPS NEO-6M module, ESP8266 etc.) connecting to Arduino Uno via Atlas Scientific serial port expander 8:1

Hardware:

1. Arduino Uno
2. Atlas Scientific serial port expander 8:1
3. GPS NEO-6M module
4. ESP8266 Wifi module

Arduino Uno to GPS module we are able to get latitude and longitude values, below is the code for the same:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

long lat, lon;
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(6, 5);
TinyGPS gps;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (gpsSerial.available()) {
    if (gps.encode(gpsSerial.read())) {
      gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
      Serial.print("Position:");
      Serial.print("lat:"); Serial.print(lat); Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print("long:"); Serial.println(lon);
    }
  }
}
```

Our requirement is that we have four sensors that need to be connected to an Arduino Uno. For that we used an Atlas Scientific hardware serial port expander 8:1.

Below is the code which we are working to get the GPS coordinates:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> // we have to include the SoftwareSerial library, or else we can't use it

#define rx 8 // define what pin rx is going to be
#define tx 9 // define what pin tx is going to be

SoftwareSerial mySerial(rx, tx); //define how the soft serial port is going to work
    
int s1 = 6; // Arduino pin 6 to control pin S1
int s2 = 5; // Arduino pin 5 to control pin S2
int s3 = 4; // Arduino pin 4 to control pin S3
    
const uint8_t module_count = 8; // number of modules connected to the serial port expander 1=Port1, 2= Port2 and so on
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Set the hardware serial port to 115200
  mySerial.begin(9600); // Set baud rate for the software serial port to 9600
    
  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);  // Set the digital pin as output
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);  // Set the digital pin as output
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);  // Set the digital pin as output
}
    
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) { // if we get data from the computer
    char c = Serial.read();
    for (uint8_t i = 1; i <= module_count; i++) { // loop through the modules
      Serial.print("Connecting to Port: ");
      Serial.println(i);
      open_port(i);               // open the port
      mySerial.print(c);          // print character to port
      delay(100);                 // insert a delay to wait for the reply
      if (mySerial.available()) { // print reply to serial monitor
        while (mySerial.available()) {
          Serial.println(mySerial.read());
          if (gps.encode(mySerial.read())) {
            gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
            Serial.print("Position:");
            Serial.print("lat:"); Serial.print(lat);
            Serial.print(" ");
            Serial.print("long:"); Serial.println(lon);
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        Serial.print("No response received");
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}

    void open_port(uint8_t _port) {                                  //this function controls what port is opened on the serial port expander
    
      if (_port < 1 || module_count > 8)_port = 1;                //if the value of the port is within range (1-8) then open that port. If it's not in range set it to port 1
      uint8_t port_bits = _port - 1;
    
      digitalWrite(s1, bitRead(port_bits, 0));               //Here we have two commands combined into one.
      digitalWrite(s2, bitRead(port_bits, 1));               //The digitalWrite command sets a pin to 1/0 (high or low)
      digitalWrite(s3, bitRead(port_bits, 2));               //The bitRead command tells us what the bit value is for a specific bit location of a number
      delay(2);                                         //this is needed to make sure the channel switching event has completed
    }
```

Kindly guide us in sorting the issue; we are having an issue with `gps.encode(mySerial.read())`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please help us in sorting code issue with atlas scientific serial port expander 8:1

Comment: You may want to tell us what the issue is.

Comment: Updated the post kindly guide us

Comment: You still haven't told us what the issue is, only where you think it is. Also, please don't post the question again as an answer.

Comment: Issue we are facing is gps coordinates(latitude and longitude values) we are not getting in serial monitor,when we connect gps module to arduino uno via atlas scientific hardware serial port expander 8:1 .

Answer (score 0):

Issue was sorted out by ourselves,
Below is the working code for the same ,

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>                           //we have to include the SoftwareSerial library, or else we can't use it
#define rx 3                                         //define what pin rx is going to be
#define tx 2                                          //define what pin tx is going to be
SoftwareSerial mySerial(rx, tx);                      //define how the soft serial port is going to work
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>
int s1 = 6;                                           //Arduino pin 6 to control pin S1
int s2 = 5;                                           //Arduino pin 5 to control pin S2
int s3 = 4;                                           //Arduino pin 4 to control pin S3
int i;
const uint8_t module_count = 8;                       //number of modules connected to the serial port expander 1=Port1, 2= Port2 and so on
TinyGPS  gps;
gps_fix fix;
long lat, lon;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                 //Set the hardware serial port to 115200
  mySerial.begin(9600);                               //set baud rate for the software serial port to 9600

  pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);                                //Set the digital pin as output
  pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);                                //Set the digital pin as output
  pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);                                //Set the digital pin as output

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {                           //if we get data from the computer
    char c = Serial.read();
    for (uint8_t i = 1; i <= module_count; i++) {    // loop through the modules
      Serial.print("Connecting to Port: ");
      Serial.println(i);
      open_port(i);                                  // open the port
      Serial.print(c);                             //print character to port
      delay(1000);                                    //insert a delay to wait for the reply
      //Serial.println(Serial.available());
      if (Serial.available()) {
        //Serial.println(gps.available(Serial));//print reply to serial monitor
        while (Serial.available()) {
          //Serial.write(mySerial.read());
          //Serial.write(gps.encode(mySerial.read()));
          //Serial.println(mySerial.available());
          //Serial.println(gps.encode(mySerial.read()));
          if (mySerial.available()>0) {
            //Serial.println(gps.encode(mySerial.read()));
            char d = byte(mySerial.read());
            //Serial.println(d);
            if (gps.encode(d)) {
              gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
              Serial.print("Position:");
              Serial.print("lat:"); Serial.print(lat); Serial.print(" ");
              Serial.print("long:"); Serial.println(lon);
            }
          }

        }
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
  }
}




void open_port(uint8_t _port) {                                  //this function controls what port is opened on the serial port expander

  if (_port < 1 || module_count > 8)_port = 1;                //if the value of the port is within range (1-8) then open that port. If it's not in range set it to port 1
  uint8_t port_bits = _port - 1;

  digitalWrite(s1, bitRead(port_bits, 0));               //Here we have two commands combined into one.
  digitalWrite(s2, bitRead(port_bits, 1));               //The digitalWrite command sets a pin to 1/0 (high or low)
  digitalWrite(s3, bitRead(port_bits, 2));               //The bitRead command tells us what the bit value is for a specific bit location of a number
  delay(2);                                         //this is needed to make sure the channel switching event has completed
}
```